# BULK INSERT error when the file location changed to remote share

Tags: sql-server

I am getting following error on BULK INSERT after the file location was changed to remote share. Before it used to be a shared folder in local drive and we never ran into this issue. I am running this BULK INSERT from my local PC connecting to SQL Server via SSMS.

[image]

I have made sure both SQL server and file permissions are in place.

Before when I ran this command from SSMS, it was \\SQLServer\FTP location which was a shared folder in local drive in that SQL Server but now I changed the file location to a network share \\Fileshare\FTP and have the above error but both SQL service account (domain account) and me (domain account) have elevated permission on that new location.

Any help or suggestions!!

Thanks,

Comment: If the instance is local you must check the permission to access the file, but if you are accessing from your computer to a server (remote access) you have to specify the path in the server, so that means you should include the file in a server directory not in your local.  "BULK INSERT Table
FROM 'C:\bulk\usuarios_prueba.csv' -- This is server path not local
WITH 
  (
     FIELDTERMINATOR =',',
     ROWTERMINATOR ='\n'
  ); "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally worked....

I had to configure Kerberos Authentication following the guide from this link https://thesqldude.com/2011/12/30/how-to-sql-server-bulk-insert-with-constrained-delegation-access-is-denied/.

Of course, I had to make adjustments to suit our environment and had to involve Active Directory Admin for creating SPNs and enabling DELEGATION properties.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can identify three circumstances that might generate this issue:

1. From [the SQLAuthority Blog](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/02/18/sql-server-cannot-open-backup-device-operating-system-error-1326-logon-failure-unknown-user-name-bad-password/), full detail on a related backup issue where there is a cross-domain link (in this case, from a workgroup to a full domain).
2. There are also two other possible answers in the question [Cannot bulk load because the file could not be opened. Operating system error code 1326(Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785183/cannot-bulk-load-because-the-file-could-not-be-opened-operating-system-error-co) here on StackOverflow. We can discount the first one (login permissions) because you stated that you had permissions, but the other solution (*I fixed it by adding the SQL Server port number to the connection string in SSIS, forcing SSIS to access SQL Server through TCP/IP instead of Named Pipes.*) could apply. Try forcing a connection to the server using TCP/IP.

All of these issues appear to be related to having an attempt at cross-domain communication. If this is the issue with you, one or more of these fixes should be applicable to your issue.

  -

Comment: 1. All servers involved are in the same domain infrastructure.
2. Permissions are in place in both Fileshare and the SQL server. I am not sure about forcing to change the connection. Also that the SQL server has dynamic port.